# Can't get properties from COM object using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, com

I have COM object variable of type PIBatch. Interface metadata shown below.

When I trying to get properties or other members using reflection I get only default member "BatchID".

[image: PIBatch metadata]

[image: Reflection results]

How can I get other members? "StartTime", for example?

Comment: Your code should work as expected (I tried it)... Where do you call `type.GetMembers()`?

Comment: COM does not support reflection, you have to rely on the interop types that are generated by Tlbimp.exe and stored in the interop library.  Apparently the IDE uses a different one than your program.  That happens.  Maybe you got an old one in the GAC, that's just an uninformed guess.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to find out more.